# import js file from another js file in browser

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to import a `test1.js` file into html that imports the `test _func` function from `test2.js`, but it doesn't work, browser doesn't make request for `test2.js`

test.html

```html
<script src="test1.js" />
```

test1.js

```js
import { test_func } from 'test2.js';
console.log(test_func());
```

test2.js

```js
export function test_func() {
  return "Hi!";
}
```

I also tried adding the string `<script type="module" src="test2.js" />` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js" />` to the beginning of the `test.html` file, but that didn't work.

Comment: First of `<script src="test1.js" />` should be `<script src="test1.js"></script>` sadly browsers do not understand SCRIPT tag used as a void tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In index.html use:

```html
<script src="./test1.js" type="module"></script>
```

in test1.js make sure to use paths relative to the current file `./` (so that the interpreter does not confuses them as *named* node_modules imports, packages) like:

```js
import { test_func } from './test2.js';
console.log(test_func());
```

test2.js is pretty much unchanged:

```js
export function test_func() {
    return "Hi!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try writing the path to the file. Like => src="./test2.js" ( if test2.js  test is in the same folder as the index)